# On which SE site can I ask questions about migrants and refugees?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm planning on making a video that depicts a map of the locations of the deaths of migrants and refugees that attempt to cross the Mediterranean Sea as time progresses. In particular, I'd like to show the country of origin of those who passed away. The International Organization for Migration (IOM) has collected [data](https://missingmigrants.iom.int/downloads) on migrant deaths. In their [methodology](https://missingmigrants.iom.int/methodology), it is explained which variables ought to be included in the data sets.

However, some variables seem to be missing. In particular, the “Country of Origin” and “Region of Origin” variables are excluded from the data sets. I've already contacted the IOM about this, but so far they haven't responded to my query.

**Question**: on which SE page should I ask questions on data regarding migrants and refugees? I've considered Politics.SE and Geography.SE, but I'm not sure whether these pages are appropriate.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com if you're specifically looking to purchase the data?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Interesting suggestion, I will certainly take a look. Why do you think I should purchase the data though? You don't believe it's something the IOM can put online for free?

Comment: Doubt there's SE site for that, looks like something internal with IOM

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you do purchase the data @Max, just that opendata wouldn't be able to help you with commercial relationships as then the data wouldn't be open... I realised I missed a "not" in my previous comment.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Ah alright, I understand.

Comment: Well, Travel.SE has [regugees tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refugees) but it's meant for "Questions about travel as a refugee or asylum-seeker, as defined under international law" (the tag wiki) so not sure it fits your case.

Comment: Max, you can try a [tag search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bimmigration%5D) on our main site - but trying "migration" returns over 46 thousand results, almost all computer related; so that word wouldn't be a good choice here. Each site has a help section explaining what is on-topic in the (?) (upper right) and an associated meta site - explaining to ask for questions similar to your own, where you can find new tags and whether a particular question is on topic for a particular site. -- Sometimes specialty questions have a DIY aspect to the research, answers are not readily available.

Comment: There is no “Geography.SE”.  You may be thinking of the [gis.se] (GIS) Stack Exchange but questions there about open data are usually referred to the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are wanting to ask questions about an open dataset so I think the site you should use is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com).